# HttpContext Null Error

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am building an application heavily modelled off of the tutorial [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer). It is, in essence an online store application where when the user arrives at the site it assigns a unique string Id which the application uses to store what the user selected in the database. The string identifies the users shopping cart.

I have some client-side JavaScript using D3.js that needs to send some information back to the server. I have added a web service (.asmx) which works nicely for receiving the data but after it is received the server goes to find the user's information in the database but can't re-generate the unique Id.

The tutorial gave me a function which returns the string Id and works well before the asmx function is called by the JavaScript. I can not figure out why I get this error only after the web service runs.

The function which gets the Id

```
    public string GetVirusId()
    {
        //Line where I get the error
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[DescriptionSessionKey] == null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[DescriptionSessionKey] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class.     
                Guid tempDescriptionId = Guid.NewGuid();
                HttpContext.Current.Session[DescriptionSessionKey] = tempDescriptionId.ToString();
            }
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[DescriptionSessionKey].ToString();
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Message:    "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

My asmx web service file

```
namespace Trojan
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for updateGraph
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class updateGraph : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public bool analyseGraph(int x)
        {
            bool B = true;
            using (VirusDescription virus = new VirusDescription())
            {
                B = virus.updateGraph(x);
            }
            return B;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're learning ASP.NET, it's probably a good idea to learn Web API instead of ASMX, as those aren't being supported by Microsoft anymore. Also, when you get an error, you should state which line is causing it. And if it's a NullReferenceException, you should state which object is null. Your title makes it sound like HttpContext is null.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently session support is turned off by default for web methods. You can read more about it [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx)

I changed my web service method to below and it now works nicely:

```
namespace Trojan
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for updateGraph
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class updateGraph : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public bool analyseGraph(int x)
        {
            bool B = true;
            using (VirusDescription virus = new VirusDescription())
            {
                B = virus.updateGraph(x);
            }
            return B;
        }
    }
}
```